# How to write mathematical formulae?

Tags: feature-request

On [Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/), it is possible to write mathematical formulae in [LaTeX](https://www.latex-project.org/)-style. Is it also possible on Chess Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is $not possible$ at the moment.

[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216606/which-stack-exchange-sites-use-mathjax/216607#216607) is a list of Stack Exchange sites which support MathJax, but Chess is not one of them.

Comment: there is a website aops.com, where there is a resource available for use that allows for typesetting into LaTeX, then copy-pasting into here as an image. It's called LaTeX TeXeR, and can be found in the 'Resources' section. I think that you can use it without having an account.

Comment: Link here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/texer